# Bootstrap HTML form, MySQL query result

Tags: php, html, mysql, twitter-bootstrap

I'm in the process of migrating a Drupal build out to Bootstrap framework. In the new Bootstrap framework, I've built out a form to pull results from a database.

Bootstrap form HTML:

```
    <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="post" action="<?php echo lookup_dosearchx() ?>">
<br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="county2" class="col-sm-3 control-label">County:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="text" name="county2" id="county2" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter County Name" required />
</div>
</div>
<hr>
<center><i>Include Payroll Notes:</i></center><br>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="employee" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Employee:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<select class="form-control" name="employee" id="employee" placeholder="Enter Employee Name" /><option>Any</option></select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="startdate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">State Date (mm/dd/yyyy):</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<input type="date" name="startdate" id="startdate" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Start Date" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="enddate" class="col-sm-3 control-label">End Date (mm/dd/yyyy):</label>
<div class="col-sm-6"> 
<input type="date" name="enddate" id="enddate" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter End Date" />
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="fulltext" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Fulltext Query:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<textarea class="form-control" name="fulltext" id="fulltext" rows="4" /></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="contain" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Phrase:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<textarea class="form-control" name="contain" id="contain" rows="4" /></textarea>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="jobid" class="col-sm-3 control-label">VCS Job Code:</label>
<div class="col-sm-6">
<select class="form-control" name="jobid" id="jobid" placeholder="Enter Job Code" /><option>Any</option></select>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
<button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<br>
</form>
```

I was provided with a large PHP query set from the prior build out, but that code isn't working when I hit submit. The database is connecting fine as I had trouble getting that to work before.

Would it be possible to be pointed in the direction of a simple example or recommended way to build out the PHP query code I'm calling out?

Comment: How can html bug the php code ?? unless the names of the input fields dont match the ones used in the php file

Comment: All the input fields match. When I type something in the "County" label and hit Submit, nothing happens.

Comment: the button must be having a name attribute, or you must have missed a required field

Comment: Would it be possible for you to examine the PHP file I'm using as part of this form?

Comment: It's a 13KB file, I commented out a lot of it to initially get the database connection to work

Comment: O_o its 1am where i'm at. How will you show me the code.?

Comment: I could email it over for review. Or would it simply be easier to build out my PHP query from scratch to match the input fields in the HTML above?

Comment: Unless you find someone to check the code my suggestion is to build one from scratch. Are you new to php?

Comment: Yes, fairly new. I'm able to get things going with the database request. It's more the permissions that I'm new with and setting the query object. Any chance you can point me in the direction of a good tutorial to get started from scratch?

Comment: Use phpmyadmin for database management, it makes things faster. You can look at youtube for tutorials. Youtube helps alot when your a beginner